# Unable to use custom git commands on Mac

Tags: shell, zsh, git, macos

I created a script like shown [here](https://gitbetter.substack.com/p/automate-repetitive-tasks-with-custom?s=r) to simplify clearing out my git remotes.

- Created the file with the format `git-{command}` and made it executable.
- Included  file in `PATH`.

The script seems to work if I directly execute it. But as far as I can understand, I should be able to run these scripts directly from `git`. i.e., `./git-clean-remote origin` works, but `git clean-remote origin` does not.

But as you can see from the screenshot below, I cannot seem to get the command to work. Am I missing something obvious?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think you need to re-edit because both commands are the same (not matching the image)
2. the `PATH` variable should not have the full executable in it, just the path to it, *i.e.* `${HOME}/.dotfiles/git/`

Comment: Thanks! that was indeed the problem :) 

Also, thanks for the first point, i fixed that as well